# Duplicate Task from one Project to another

Tags: vba, copy-paste, ms-project

I'm new to VBA in MS Projects, so I have a really simple question.
I want to copy a task from Project1 and create a new task in Project2 containing information in all fields.

I can only figure out how to copy one field at a time (e.g. "Name"), but how do I copy all fields?

```
Sub CopyTask()

Dim source As Project
Dim destination As Project

Set source = Application.Projects("Project1")
Set destination = Application.Projects("Project2")

destination.Tasks.Add.Name = source.Tasks(1).Name
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all of the fields (300+) and transfer the information piece by piece, but using [EditCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.editcopy) and [EditPaste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.editpaste) are the best way to do it.

This sample code copies the first task from the source project and pastes it to the destination project. Optionally use the [SelectRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.selectrow) method on the destination project to control where it gets pasted.

```
Sub CopyTask()

    Dim source As Project
    Dim destination As Project

    Set source = Application.Projects("Project1")
    Set destination = Application.Projects("Project2")

    source.Activate
    SelectRow Row:=1, RowRelative:=False
    EditCopy

    destination.Activate
    EditPaste

End Sub
```

Note: one might think there would be a "cleaner" way to do this, but the Project API is not nearly as comprehensive as the Excel API.